# Can anyone explain this exception

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee

When i run my client i am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'http' not registered
```

So i registered it in the scheme registry

Now it's showing

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'https' not registered
```

I am working in a proxied environment and i have provided all the proxy details

Comment: Without having more information (code) it is quite hard to tell what's missing, but I bet you didn't register proxy details or other mapping information for 'https'. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Register "https" too. It should help as long registering "http" helped.

Comment: @above: i tried registering both but it didn't help..But it started giving different type of error. windows cannot load  c:\winnt\krb5.ini

Comment: may be you're missing that file?

Comment: @above: Actually i found that the authentication scheme we are using is not ntlm it's kerberos/spnego. we need to change accordingly to that